# Insert multiple rows from array

Tags: php, mysql

I need help to insert data into mysql. I am unable to find the problem in the code below why data is not inserted into database. When I am submitting the form this message comes : `Notice: Undefined variable: asd in...`

```
<?php
$q = mysql_query("select `cus_id`, `date`, `mobile`, 
    least(`t1`, `t2`, `t3`, `t4`) as min 
    from `table1`");

while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){

$asd = array(`cus_id` =>$r['cus_id'], 
             `mobile` =>$r['mobile'], 
             `date`   =>$r['date'], 
             `credit` =>$r['min']);
}

$sql = array();

foreach((array)$asd as $row){

$sql[] = '("'.mysql_real_escape_string($row['cus_id']).'", 
                                     '.$row['mobile'].', 
                                     '.$row['date'].', 
                                     '.$row['min_total'].'
           )';
}

$stmt = mysql_query('INSERT INTO `single` (`cus_id`, `mobile`, `date`, `credit`) 
                     VALUES '.implode(',', $sql));                                    

if(!$stmt){ 
echo "error". mysql_error();
}else{
$_SESSION['s']="Payment successfully saved";
header('location:final.php');
}
?>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: 1. You are not quoting your strings, 2. You are not escaping your strings, 3. You should not be using `mysql_*`.

Comment: What datatype of `date`? Why don't you use parentheses to wrap inserting variables?

Comment: `datatype of date` is varchar(255). I don't know how to use parentheses to wrap inserting variables. Plz help.

Comment: @jeroen  will you plz help me how will I convert this code with `mysqli`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I convert the above query into mysqli, then will the code be below:

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mumbai');
$q = "select `cus_id`, `date`, `mobile`, 
      least(`t1`, `t2`, `t3`, `t4`) as min 
      from `table1`";

$asd = array(); 
$result = mysqli_query($link, $q);
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

$asd = array(`cus_id` =>$r['cus_id'], 
             `mobile` =>$r['mobile'], 
             `date`   =>$r['date'], 
             `credit` =>$r['min']);
}

$sql = array();

foreach((array)$asd as $row){

$sql[] = '("'.mysqli_real_escape_string($row['cus_id']).'", 
                                 '.$row['mobile'].', 
                                 '.$row['date'].', 
                                 '.$row['min_total'].'
       )';
}
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO single 
               (`cus_id`, `mobile`, `date`, `time`, `credit`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'isssi', implode(',', $sql));                  

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

if(!$stmt){ 
echo "error". mysqli_error($link);
}else{
$_SESSION['s']="Payment successfully saved";
header('location:final.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: Using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` with a prepared statement demonstrates a misunderstanding about how to use prepared statements properly.

Answer (score 0):

before your while loop add an `$asd` variable.

```
$asd = array();

while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
....
```

then in your foreach you can remove the `(array)`

```
foreach($asd as $row){
....
```

no more `Notice: Undefined variable: asd in...`

Comment: I have added `$asd = array();`  Now the message comes : `You have an error in your SQL syntax........` I am unable to insert all data rows at once. Also a similar line here `$sql = array();` Will I keep the line or remove ?

Comment: can you show the complete error? Not just `You have an error in your SQL syntax` followed by `....`

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: What is the difference between `$sql = array();` and  `$asd = array();`?    Will I have to keep both line in the code?

Comment: you can delete $sql = array() if you don't use it @rockya